# Problems with Chrome Extension developing to change anchors in webpages

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to build a chrome extension which check all the links of the pages which currently viewing by the user, and checks target of that link,if it is "http://www.youtube.com" then the extension will change it to "https://www.youtube.com"

but my extension is not working!!

here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Youtube Host Changer",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "description" : "It changes Youtube HTTP host to HTTPS",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
     "matches": ["file:///*/*","http://*/*","https://*/*"],
     "js": ["jquery.js", "youtube_host.js"]
   }
    ]
  }
```

and here is my youtube_host.js

```
/*
* Part of the Youtube Host Change Project.
* Author : Ahmad Faiyaz
*/
function change_links(){
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var link= nodes[i].href;
        link=link.replace("http://www.youtube","https://www.youtube");
        nodes[i].href=link;
 };
}

window.onload = change_links();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after adding

```
"permissions":["<all_urls>"]
```

to `manifest.json` file.

**Final manifest.json file**

```
{
  "name": "Youtube Host Changer",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "description" : "It changes Youtube HTTP host to HTTPS",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
     "matches": ["file:///*/*","http://*/*","https://*/*"],
     "js": ["jquery.js","youtube_host.js"]
   }
    ],
    "permissions":["<all_urls>"]
  }
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: thanks, now it works for this page https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34972503/test.html,

but how to make it work for [link](http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/ph100/CourseRev/1/Unit/3001/Nugget/5001) 
this kind of page ? changing the tag "a" to "iframe" doesnot work..

Comment: @AhmadFaiyaz: It works for me , iframe has `src` not `href`; did you make that change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write

```
...
link = link.replace("http://www.youtube","https://www.youtube");
...
```

`string.replace` doesn't change the original value but returns a new result-string.